# Permission.photos request is not working on my current device

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm planning to implement a function to include images from the user's device by the user. But unfortunately, it is not working as expected in Flutter application. I've did some research and implement it but not accomplished. The following **D/permissions_handler( 1361): No permissions found in manifest for: []9** occurs when request the permission

[image]

```
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:snapup/global/string_holder.dart';

class AddItemFromImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String company, productName;
  final bool isImageInput;
  const AddItemFromImageScreen(
      {Key? key,
      required this.company,
      required this.productName,
      required this.isImageInput})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddItemFromImageScreen> createState() => _AddItemFromImageScreenState();
}

class _AddItemFromImageScreenState extends State<AddItemFromImageScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _itemNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemDescriptionController =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemPriceController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemDiscountController = TextEditingController();
  int _currentHorizontalIntValue = 0;
  double _appBarBottomBtnPosition = 28.0, _textInputRad = 15.0;
  bool _isVisible = true;
  String _title = "", _imageUrl = "";
  var _finalImagePath;
  var _context, _dateModified, _dateAded;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (widget.productName.isEmpty) {
      _fetchProductData();
    }
    _loadPermission();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _itemNameController.dispose();
    _itemDescriptionController.dispose();
    _itemPriceController.dispose();
    _itemDiscountController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          // Define the default brightness and colors.
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primaryColor:
              widget.isImageInput == true ? Colors.red : Colors.orange,
          colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
            primary: widget.isImageInput == true ? Colors.red : Colors.orange,
            secondary: widget.isImageInput == true ? Colors.red : Colors.orange,
          ),

          // Define the default font family.
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        ),
        child: _content());
  }

  _content() {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: !widget.isImageInput
          ? AppBar(
              title: Text(
                _title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            )
          : null,
      body: widget.isImageInput
          ? _generateSliverAppBarContent()
          : _generateNormalAppBarContent(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () => _pushToCloud(),
        label: Text(
          AppStringHolder.btnSave,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.save_as_rounded,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _generateSliverAppBarContent() {}

  _generateNormalAppBarContent() {}

  _pushToCloud() {}

  _fetchProductData() {}

  _loadPermission() async {
    if(await Permission.photos.status != PermissionStatus.granted){
      Permission.photos.request();
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm using the below permissions in android menifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you double-checked the **AndroidManifest** files and made sure that you put all the necessary requests and still facing this issue, read below.

**D/permissions_handler( 1361): No permissions found in manifest for: []9**
is displayed because you are asking for permission to the wrong Android SDK level.

If the device's Android SDK is 32 or lower, ask for **Permissions.storage**
Else, use **Permission.photos**

Please take a look at the documentation/comments in **permission_handler** package(line 89)
https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/main/permission_handler_platform_interface/lib/src/permissions.dart

In Flutter, you can check the androidSdkVersion by using DeviceInfoPlugin.
https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

Simply calling

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  final androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
  final androidSdkVersion = androidInfo.version.sdkInt;
  if (androidSdkVersion >= 33) {
    Permission.photos.request();
  }
}
```

should solve this issue.

One thing I want to say though, is that, the error descriptions are way too cryptic. []9 means

```
 static const photos = Permission._(9);
```

inside the **permissions.dart** folder of the package.